# Inconsistent behaviour when an exception is thrown in a for comprehension

Tags: scala

I noticed that **for comprehension** behaves inconsistently when an exception is thrown in the first line inside it versus any other line.

Consider the following example code:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

object ForComprehensionTester {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val result: Future[String] = for {
      x <- returnString() // Comment out this line and exception will not be captured, but propagated.
      y <- throwException()
    } yield y

    result.onComplete {
      case Success(s) => System.out.println(s"Success: $s")
      case Failure(t) => System.out.println(s"Exception captured!")
    }

    Thread.sleep(2000)
  }

  def returnString() = Future {
    "content"
  }

  def throwException(): Future[String] = throw new RuntimeException
}
```

The above code results in the exception being captured and handled in **onComplete** function. But if we comment out line 8, the exception will be propagated instead.

Can someone explain what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for comprehension is the syntax sugar. You can understand the behaviour if you think in terms of `map` and `flatMap`

```
val result: Future[String] = for {
      x <- returnString() // Comment out this line and exception will not be captured, but propagated.
      y <- throwException()
    } yield y
```

the above code is converted to

```
returnString.flatMap { str =>
  throwException()
}
```

Here is the `flatMap` implementation from the standard library. `flatMap` handles the exception thrown inside it.

```
def flatMap[S](f: T => Future[S])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[S] = {
    import impl.Promise.DefaultPromise
    val p = new DefaultPromise[S]()
    onComplete {
      case f: Failure[_] => p complete f.asInstanceOf[Failure[S]]
      case Success(v) => try f(v) match {
        // If possible, link DefaultPromises to avoid space leaks
        case dp: DefaultPromise[_] => dp.asInstanceOf[DefaultPromise[S]].linkRootOf(p)
        case fut => fut.onComplete(p.complete)(internalExecutor)
      } catch { case NonFatal(t) => p failure t }
    }
    p.future
  }
```

When you comment out the `returnString` for comprehension becomes

```
throwException()
```

Note that exception thrown by the `throwException` is not handled in the function.

Declare `throwException` like below to capture the exception

```
def throwException(): Future[String] = Future { throw new RuntimeException }
```